# Valgrind - Invalid write of size 1 for strcpy

Tags: c

My swapData function basically swaps data between two node of type char*

```
17 void swapData(struct Node *node1, struct Node *node2)
18 {
19     // Create a new node "temp" that stores the data of node2
20     struct Node *temp = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
21     temp->data = malloc(strlen(node2->data));
22    
23     strcpy(temp->data,node2->data);
24    
25     // Copy data from node1 to node2
26     strcpy(node2->data,node1->data);
27    
28     // Copy data from temp to node1
29     strcpy(node1->data,temp->data);
30    
31     free(temp->data);
32     free(temp);
33  }
```

Whenever I run valgrind, it keeps giving me this output:

```
==27570== Invalid write of size 1
==27570==    at 0x4C2C00F: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27570==    by 0x400794: swapData (test4.c:23)
==27570==    by 0x400A9C: sort (list2.c:20)
==27570==    by 0x40086B: main (test4.c:49)
==27570==  Address 0x51f11dd is 0 bytes after a block of size 13 alloc'd
==27570==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27570==    by 0x40076B: swapData (test4.c:21)
==27570==    by 0x400A9C: sort (list2.c:20)
==27570==    by 0x40086B: main (test4.c:49)
==27570==
==27570== Source and destination overlap in strcpy(0x51f1130, 0x51f1130)
==27570==    at 0x4C2C085: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27570==    by 0x4007B2: swapData (test4.c:26)
==27570==    by 0x400A9C: sort (list2.c:20)
==27570==    by 0x40086B: main (test4.c:49)
==27570==
==27570== Invalid read of size 1
==27570==    at 0x4C2C002: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27570==    by 0x4007D0: swapData (test4.c:29)
==27570==    by 0x400A9C: sort (list2.c:20)
==27570==    by 0x40086B: main (test4.c:49)
==27570==  Address 0x51f11dd is 0 bytes after a block of size 13 alloc'd
==27570==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27570==    by 0x40076B: swapData (test4.c:21)
==27570==    by 0x400A9C: sort (list2.c:20)
==27570==    by 0x40086B: main (test4.c:49)
==27570==
```

I believe the problem is in strcpy in swapData. Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Can you post structure of Node and also how you are calling this function . ie what are you passing

Comment: this error is shown if you write data outside memory ie outside your memory range

Comment: While @Dere0405's answer is a good first start, it's not possible to know from your code whether the other `strcpy` calls are safe, since you have not shared the `Node` definition.

Comment: You just totally changed your question, leaving the correct answer looking silly. Please don't do that.

Comment: You're also completely ignoring the size of the memory you're copying *into*. For instance, if you allocated 20 bytes for `node1->data` and filled it, and allocated only 10 bytes for `node2->data`, then just copying `node1->data` into `node2->data` is not going to end well. You should just swap the pointers, here, there's no need to `strcpy()` anything.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thanks for the reply! How do I swap the pointers when I actually need to swap the node->data stored in 2 different nodes? Can you show me?

Comment: @viethaihp291: `char * temp = node1->data; node1->data = node2->data; node2->data = temp;`

Comment: thanks! Is it like node1->data in node1 is basically just pointing to a string and that string has no real connection with node1 whatsoever?

Comment: @viethaihp291: Yes, and that's true of any pointer. You can point them at any suitable data.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths one last question: while valgrind gives out error, my original code with strcpy still works fine if you disregard memory check. Can you explain this?

Comment: @viethaihp291: Yes, one of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior is that things work as you expect. Don't count on it. Fix all your Valgrind errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not only do you need to add one to your malloc length, but also you can't swap strings using strcpy like you are doing.  What if the first string was malloced with 10 bytes and the second with 29 bytes?  When you copy to swap, you will overrun the first string's buffer.  It would be best to swap the pointers.  If `data` is defined as a fixed length array, then what you are doing is ok, but then `temp` could also be the same sized array instead of a node.

Comment: If `data` was defined as a fixed length array, then `temp->data = malloc(strlen(node2->data));` would give pretty serious problems.

Comment: True.  Which means that the code is definitely broken.

Answer (score 14):

You need to malloc one more byte for temp->data

```
temp->data = malloc(strlen(node2->data)+1);
```

This is because you need the final byte to store then '\0' indicating the end of the string.

Comment: Also, there's always `strdup`. And `strndup`.

Comment: @Dere0405 thanks, I added +1 and there is still one error "Source and destination overlap in strcpy". Please see the update!

Comment: actually some other problems came up so I will have to review my code totally, but thanks for the answer!